# How to eliminate circular solutions in unification?

Tags: python, logic-programming

I use the next [unification lib](https://github.com/mrocklin/unification).

```
from unification import *

x1 = var('x1')

unify((x1, 1), x1) # {~x1: (~x1, 1)}
```

Can you please suggest how to eliminate such circular solutions (`~x1` references to itself)? For my particular task it is not a solution. `unify` should return `False`.

How it can be a solution? `((x1, 1), 1) is not eq (x1, 1)`

If it is not possible to do in library itself. Can you please suggest an algorithm to track such circular references? Example of another solution to reject:

```
{~x1: (~s1_1, (~s1_2, ~s1_3)),
 ~x2: (~s1_1, ~s1_2),
 ~x3: (~s1_1, ~s1_3),
 ~s1_1: ~i1,
 ~i1: (~x3, ~s1_3),
 ~i2: (~s1_2, ~s1_3),
 ~s1_2: (~x3, ~s1_3)}
```

~x3: (~s1_1, ~s1_3) -> ~x3: (~i1, ~s1_3) -> ~x3: ((~x3, ~s1_3), ~s1_3)